# How can I get a div's border width/color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd like to detect if a div has border. If so, I'd like to change the border color to gray. Here's my code but does not work.

```
var ele = document.get...;
if(ele.style.borderColor)
{
   ele.style.borderColor='666666';
}
```

The `ele.style.borderColor` is always null. 
BTW, I can't use JQuery here.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ele = document.getElementById('a'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(ele, null),
    sides = ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'],
    maxBorder = 0;

for (var i = 0, length = sides.length; i < length; i++) {
    maxBorder = Math.max(maxBorder, parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('border-' + sides[i] + '-width')));
}

if (maxBorder) {
    ele.style.borderColor = '#666666';
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Yv93r/).

Comment: Thanks man, but, `style = window.getComputedStyle(ele, null)' is always null, just tested in chrome, osx, latest version.

Comment: @icespace Which Chrome? I just tested it in Chrome 11 on OS X and it worked fine.

Comment: yeah,yeah, it works fine. Sorry. I guess some other error in my script. Thank you very much. 8-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the border color, and don't try to read any property.

If the element has **no** border, setting the color won't have any effect.

Comment: Good thinking, I will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have made is that you haven't specified the '#' sign before the color hex code
So You will have to make a little change:
`ele.style.borderColor='#666666';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting a null because you are missing the hyphen in the middle of the property.  "border-color"

Since you can't use jquery here I would look at all the css border properties to determine if it has a border such as border-style, border-width and border-color.

Comment: Try to get 'ele.style.border-color' in chrome encounter an error.

Comment: You can't use the hyphen when accessing object properties like that.